# Leaking hose bib

Tags: plumbing

Hose bib had been leaking. I replaced it and now it is leaking from the connection between the pipe and the hose bib.  I did put some of of that stuff that looks like tape on the end. What else can I do to stop this annoying leak?!

[image]

Comment: Make sure you wrap the tape in the correct direction. 3-4 wraps usually does it.

Comment: More tape, one more spin on the hose bib but hold that pipe fitting with a second wrench or you can twist the entire pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Take the faucet off, clean the threads of the pipe tape, install 3 wraps of new tape in the direction of the threads, then add a coating of RTV silicone, re-install the faucet and wait till the next day to turn the water on to the faucet. I have used this fix on many hard to stop thread leaks on both hot and cold water lines.